# RegEx: remove |

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a="value1%7Cvalue2=%20a%20|value3"
```

url is encoded in such a way that for some values it is encoded as  %7C and some places it is | sign only.

Without decoding this string how to remove everything that comes after first | using regular expression?

Comment: `indexOf` + `slice`?

Comment: `a.replace(/\|.*/, '')` or `a.replace(/\|.*/, '|')`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Do you want %7C to also be considered a "|"?

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex, as you asked:

```
var a = "value1%7Cvalue2=%20a%20|value3"
var regex = /\|.*/;
a = a.replace(regex, "");
console.log(a);
```

We match the `|` followed by an unlimited number of characters, and replace the match with the empty string.

It's much easier to do with a `split`, though.

```
a = a.split('|')[0]
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why regex? Try split.

```
var a="value1%7Cvalue2=%20a%20|value3"; 
var b = a.split('|')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

see this demo https://regex101.com/r/dE0jW4/2

```
/([^|]*)\|.*/

var re = /([^|]*)\|.*/gm; 
var str = 'value1%7Cvalue2=%20a%20|value3"';
var subst = '$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```